# How do I acquire and maintain friends?

Tags: the-sims-2

(1) Some people are just mean. It's hard to start to build a good relationship with them. It seems the only thing that I can do is keep using the safe Talk option with them and hope it slowly edges our relationship status up until I can unlock some more powerful socialization options. How do you think that should I start?

(2) Promotions can require having a certain number of friends. I feel like I can't fit enough socialization into my Sim's day, let alone maintain the formidable 8 friends to get promoted to Business Tycoon at the top of the [Business](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Business_%28career%29#The_Sims_2) career track. What should I do?

I think it's rather important to denote that this is The Sims 2 (TS2) for consoles (in particular, the Nintendo GameCube), because I think The Sims 2 is rather different between console and PC.

Comment: You gag them and tie them up (acquiring process). Drag them all the way to your house and keep them in the basement (maintenance process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use aphrodisiac meals to put the target in a good mood. Giving the meal to the target raises the relationship and they will want to eat it.
- Couches can become social machines. Trap a Sim on a couch. Block their one-tile exit. Now, any Sims seated with them will talk with them, at NO loss, raising their relationship, albeit slowly, AND filling the Social meter.
- Marry to obtain control of another Sim. Divorcées can still be controlled afterward. This is useful when the target is in a good enough relationship to get married to another Sim that you control, but you want to befriend them with another Sim.
- Although socialization with ghost interactions have 0 base consequences (by themselves, they'll never improve or worsen a relationship), socialization with ghosts can still benefit from relationship meter bonuses (i.e., +1 for being on good terms in the past) which results in 100% win for easy relationship building.
- Another way of avoiding the post-four-wins-streak loss of social interactions is to perform the social interactions outside of Direct Control mode.
- Cultivate a graveyard garden of friendship. Mourning a Sim raises your relationship with them (as long as they're not on your lot). You can mourn them for as long as your Fun is not low enough. Is it possible to mourn urns, as well as memorials? Yes.

How to kill:

- Main method: starvation: Get target on couch or bed. Trap the target by blocking their exit (such as with a cheap waste-basket). Wait until they are sure to die from starvation once they awake, then release them to die to get a tombstone of them. The visiting Sims in my games have nightmares about garbage cans until they die from hunger.
- If you're looking to kill a Sim that you control, trap them in sleep in a bed because this allows you to fast-fast-forward when all controllable Sims sleep, speeding up the starvation process.

Comment: Jesus... the actual answer is even more sadistic than @deutschZuid'd joke answer. Drug them, imprison them, sham-marry them, kill them, bury them in a neighbors garden, befriend their ghosts, and go grind crocodile tears over their corpses. All to improve your 'social skills'. ๏̯๏

Comment: You made me LOL. The closest thing to social skill is Charisma, but none of these techniques affect that, and Charisma doesn't affect socialization AFAIK. Although, you can raise Charisma by eulogizing. Your crocodile tears remark reminds me of how I tried to grind as early as possible. Didn't do one of the first objectives, which I think meant that I was still at a tutorial stage where certain motives stay static to grind more easily (and no visitors), killed a Sim, used ghost to spam scare which exacerbates Bladder, all to clean up puddles which gives XP to Cleaning, but it'd take too long.